# How to iterate over every cell of a column in a DataTable to check its text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table created using the jquery DataTables API. I have a column that indicated word frequencies of each word within my datatable. If the frequency is < 40, then I would like to change that cell to not say an integer reflecting the word frequency, but rather, have it say "unranked."

So I need to iterate over every cell in that column to check the text in it. What is the best way to do that?

I looked up some questions online and tried to write the following, but this tells me I am trying to find property ".each" of an object that is undefined

```
    words_table.column("corpus_rank").nodes().each( function(cell, i) {
    console.log(words_table.cell(i, 2).data());
});
```

I also perhaps shouldn't use code I don't understand... I have no clue what the "i" is supposed to mean. So if someone could explain this in a simple way that would be helpful.

Adding some more code. There is a lot that goes into generating this DataTable, which is why I don't necessarily think code is helpful. However, someone did ask about the context of the code and they made me think about something.

```
        var filter_states = determineFilterState(); 
var word_data_filtered = filterWordData(filter_states); //This line and the one above are responsible for determining which columns are displayed.
words_table = $("#words_generated").DataTable({
    "data" : word_data_filtered,
    "columns" : columns,    
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 100,
});
```

When this datatable is initialized, I hide the column containing word frequencies. I run the code that I posted originally to iterate over each cell of the word frequency column shortly after.

`column.nodes()`, according to documentation, obtains `<th>` and `<td>` tags corresponding to the column https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().nodes()

I've worked with DataTables long enough now to wonder if... Perhaps `words_table`.column("corpus_rank").nodes()` returns an undefined value because I do not have that column displayed so its  and  tags aren't present. I'm pretty sure this API does more than just make non-visible columns "display hidden."

edit: I moved my line of code to another part of my js file to make sure that the word frequency column was displayed. But the expression `words_table.column("corpus_rank").nodes()` returns an undefined value. Removing the .nodes() method returns me the correct column object. "corpus_rank" is what the name of the column was set to (again, using DataTables API).

Comment: `i` typically stands for array index in this situation

Comment: by data table do you mean an html table that is storing your data?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the jquery DataTables API.
Well, it is a table.

Comment: what kind of object is `words_table` is? what is before that line of code? I don't think that the `i` has anything to do with the problem. anyways if it's jquery, then the parameters are inverted; it should be `.each(function(index, cell){})`. look [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/). but again there's something happening before the code you posted

Comment: Hi all, just specified in an edit that `words_table` is a DataTables api object. Does this help?
DataTables ultimately creates an html table... But it's a useful API for being able to filter and edit a table.

Comment: can you post either an abstracted version of what your code is doing before you do that call or if it's not that big, then the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

Per the refrenece link you provided in question the collection is not a jQuery object and the example shows chaining `.to$()` to convert it to jQuery object.

Also the arguments for `each()` are reversed

Try:

```
 words_table.column("corpus_rank").nodes().to$().each( function(i,cell) {
    console.log(words_table.cell(i, 2).data());
});
```

Comment: Iit's very useful to now know about `$to()` but sadly this didn't work... the actual statement of `words_table.column("corpus_rank").nodes()` returns an undefined value.

Comment: Even `words_table.column("corpus_rank")` returns me the column api instance (I think... can't exactly remember the documentation right now but my console logs prove it)  but `.nodes()` is "problematic."

Comment: I've been having a lot of difficulty understanding rendering callbacks... This may partly be because of my sparse Javascript experience. I did have to use one for another column so that I could embed everything as a link.

In this context, could you show me how I"d use it? I'm assuming that I could write a function that could have a condition to check if the value is below a certain number and then change the text of the column cell if so.

Comment: See examples using function in https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [draw event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) in order to get the column of interest (refer to [nTBody](https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.models.oSettings.html#nTBody)):

> draw event: fired once the table has completed a draw.

This event has two parameters:

- event object
- settings: DataTables settings object

From the **settings** parameter you can get the **nTBody** property. This property contains a permanent reference to the tbody element.

You can convert this to a jQuery object and so you can select the column of your interest using the [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) or [:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selectors according to the column position.

For each cell contained in the column (i.e.: [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)) you can test if the element is greater than  40.

In the example I used the standard datatables example and I used the column number 4.

```
$('#example').on('draw.dt', function (e, settings) {
    $(settings.nTBody).find('tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(idx, ele) {
        if (+ele.textContent < 40) {
            ele.textContent = 'unranked';
        }
    })
}).DataTable();
```

```js
$('#example').on('draw.dt', function (e, settings) {
    $(settings.nTBody).find('tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(idx, ele) {
        if (+ele.textContent < 40) {
            ele.textContent = 'unranked';
        }
    })
}).DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2011/04/25</td>
    <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2011/07/25</td>
    <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>2009/01/12</td>
    <td>$86,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2012/03/29</td>
    <td>$433,060</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Airi Satou</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>2008/11/28</td>
    <td>$162,700</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2012/12/02</td>
    <td>$372,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>2012/08/06</td>
    <td>$137,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>2010/10/14</td>
    <td>$327,900</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>2009/09/15</td>
    <td>$205,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>2008/12/13</td>
    <td>$103,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2008/12/19</td>
    <td>$90,560</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
    <td>Support Lead</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2013/03/03</td>
    <td>$342,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>2008/10/16</td>
    <td>$470,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>2012/12/18</td>
    <td>$313,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>2010/03/17</td>
    <td>$385,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael Silva</td>
    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>2012/11/27</td>
    <td>$198,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2010/06/09</td>
    <td>$725,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gloria Little</td>
    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>2009/04/10</td>
    <td>$237,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>2012/10/13</td>
    <td>$132,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dai Rios</td>
    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>2012/09/26</td>
    <td>$217,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
    <td>Development Lead</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2011/09/03</td>
    <td>$345,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>2009/06/25</td>
    <td>$675,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>2011/12/12</td>
    <td>$106,450</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>Sidney</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>2010/09/20</td>
    <td>$85,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/10/09</td>
    <td>$1,200,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>2010/12/22</td>
    <td>$92,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>2010/11/14</td>
    <td>$357,650</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>2011/06/07</td>
    <td>$206,850</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Fiona Green</td>
    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>2010/03/11</td>
    <td>$850,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shou Itou</td>
    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2011/08/14</td>
    <td>$163,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michelle House</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>Sidney</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2011/06/02</td>
    <td>$95,400</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Suki Burks</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>2009/10/22</td>
    <td>$114,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
    <td>Technical Author</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/05/07</td>
    <td>$145,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
    <td>Team Leader</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2008/10/26</td>
    <td>$235,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>2011/03/09</td>
    <td>$324,050</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unity Butler</td>
    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/12/09</td>
    <td>$85,675</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>2008/12/16</td>
    <td>$164,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
    <td>Secretary</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>2010/02/12</td>
    <td>$109,850</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
    <td>Financial Controller</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>2009/02/14</td>
    <td>$452,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2008/12/11</td>
    <td>$136,200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
    <td>Director</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>2008/09/26</td>
    <td>$645,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2011/02/03</td>
    <td>$234,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>2011/05/03</td>
    <td>$163,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2009/08/19</td>
    <td>$139,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thor Walton</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2013/08/11</td>
    <td>$98,540</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/07/07</td>
    <td>$87,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2012/04/09</td>
    <td>$138,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2010/01/04</td>
    <td>$125,250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>2012/06/01</td>
    <td>$115,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>2013/02/01</td>
    <td>$75,650</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>2011/12/06</td>
    <td>$145,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2011/03/21</td>
    <td>$356,250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lael Greer</td>
    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>2009/02/27</td>
    <td>$103,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2010/07/14</td>
    <td>$86,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shad Decker</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>2008/11/13</td>
    <td>$183,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2011/06/27</td>
    <td>$183,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Donna Snider</td>
    <td>Customer Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I do want to ask, what are you referring to with the nth-child selector? The columns that are displayed can change in number and index. However, One thing that odes help is that the word frequency column is the last column of my table (when visible)

Comment: @ByronSmith Don't worry. If your column is the last one you can use **$(settings.nTBody).find('tr td:last-child')**  If you need to test if the element is visible you can use the jQuery **:visible** selector. You can read more about [:nth-child() Selector and so on](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Thank you, though for some reason this code didn't work... I didn't get any errors from my console, but I tried putting a console.log as the very first line for this event and that log didn't ever show. I don't think anything in the function runs.

It seemed like it was perfect though. Maybe i messed up with the selector or something?
But I think I might check this as a resolution to this problem.